# how can i use text input on iOS version of love2d

Tags: ios, emulation, love2d

I need help trying to get love2d working on my iPhone.
The Script will run but I can't get the keyboard to appear and using a bluetooth keyboard just doesn't send input.
This is the game:
https://github.com/RGFTheCoder/public-file-place/blob/master/cclite.love?raw=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use text input on mobile devices?

```
love.keyboard.setTextInput(true)
```

You can enable the on-screen keyboard on touch/mobile devices,
by using [`love.keyboard.setTextInput(enable)`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.keyboard.setTextInput) (since 0.9.0). If enabled the on-screen keyboard should appear.

You can further specify the area where the text will appear,
by using [`love.keyboard.setTextInput(enable, x, y, w, h)`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.keyboard.setTextInput) (since 0.10.0). This tells that OS to avoid covering up that area.